# How to Create a Custom Menu for Illustrator Using Extendscript?

Tags: javascript, menu, adobe-illustrator, extendscript

Salvete!  With Adobe InDesign, it is easy to create custom menus using extendscript and simply drop it into your Startup Scripts folder - you get custom menu commands that way and it works like a charm.

How can I do this for Illustrator?  Maybe it is there, but I can't find any `menu` methods in the Object Model for Illustrator, and the same script that I use for InDesign won't work for Illustrator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the DOM seems not to offer any access to any menu object, it looks like a deadend to me.
As for dropping indesign scripts within Illustrator, it's no suprise that it doesn't work. Both applications have only a very narrow set of common objects.

Comment: That is what I think too.  However, I'll wait a little while and see if anyone else has an idea.

Comment: Okay, I think you are right; it can't be done with extendscript.